# how to download a file from sharepoint without an authentication (python)

Tags: python, office365

I want to download a public file from office365 sharepoint.
the file can be downloaded and accessed without the need to authenticate.

I have seen many examples of how to download a file with authentication but I didn't find anything that does it without. how can it be done?

I'm working with python 3
and the link is looking like this:
https://XXXX.sharepoint.com/:x:/s/YYYY/ZZZZ?e=KKKK

Answer (score 0):

You can replace everything after `?` to `download=1`.
`https://xxxx.sharepoint.com/:x:/s/YYYY/ZZZZ?download=1`

```
url = "https://xxxx.sharepoint.com/:x:/s/YYYY/ZZZZ?e=KKKK"
url = url.split("?")[0] + "?download=1"

response = requests.get(url, stream=True)
total_size_in_bytes = int(response.headers.get("content-length", 0))
block_size = 1024
with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
    counter = 0
    for data in response.iter_content(block_size):
        f.write(data)
        counter += 1
        print(f"{min(100,counter*block_size/total_size_in_bytes*100):d}% done!", end="\r")
```